# Is there a way to define functions declared in a namespace in a separate .h and .cpp file?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am still kind of new to many areas of c++ and one is general .cpp and .h file organization.

I am creating a namespace with some structs and functions. I would like to declare the namespace in a .h file similar to this

```
//objectname.h
namespace ObjectName
{
   Object Function(arguments);
}
```

declarations in function.h

```
//function.h
//includes declarations used in the function definition as well
//as possibly a redundant function declaration.
Object Function(arguments);
```

then the definition in function.cpp

```
//function.cpp
#include "Function.h"
Object Function(arguments)
{
  ....
}
```

So that you can see abstractly the namespace in `objectname.h`, function particular declarations in `function.h` and function definition in `function.cpp.` As always any suggestions are greatly appreciated. (also windows based c++)

Comment: Also to justify some of the reason for this, is such. The methods are rather long and simply parse data. I think it would be fitting to have a .h/.cpp pair for each method in the namespace. And for general file keeping, having the file named after the method.

Comment: For functions, scoping using namespaces works pretty much like scoping with classes, especially `static` class functions. In other words, you need to actually specify the namespace scope.

Comment: So I need to make the changes to the `function.h` and `function.cpp` files? Should I declare/define them in the respective files using the fully qualified names? Like in `function.h` `Object ObjectName::Function(arguments);`?

Comment: I don't see the need for `function.h` to begin with, can't you just include `objectname.h` directly? Or possibly include it in `function.h`?

Comment: Yes it was mistake, sorry @Joachim Pileborg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine

```
//objectname.h
namespace ObjectName
{
   Object Function(arguments);
}
```

You don't need function.h at all.  If you want to split the namespace into several files, you would do it like:

```
//function.h
//includes declarations used in the function definition as well
//as possibly a redundant function declaration.
namespace ObjectName
{
   Object Function(arguments);
}
```

In other words you need to wrap the declaration in the namespace again.  (This is an advance topic.  I wouldn't do it.)

Function.cpp just needs to say *which* function it is defining:

```
//function.cpp
#include "ObjectName.h"
Object ObjectName::Function(arguments)
{
  ....
}
```

Note that the statement to use a header file is `#include`, not `using`

Comment: Okay, this works. I can format the project as I wanted to having a separate (yet redundant) files. As I said, the reason is simply to make things simpler for me by having a similar function declaration by the symmetry, even if it doesn't inherently require it. Basically every object has a .h and .cpp file in the project (except the namespace, no .cpp).

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works: your function.h defines *another* `Function` in the global namespace. Having two functions with the same name is exactly what namespaces are for - a library write doesn't need to worry if there's already a `Function` in any other library.

And as your .cpp defines only one of the two `Function`s, the other one is undefined and will give a link error when called.

Note that you do not need to "define" a namespace all at once. Take for instance `namespace std`, whose contents are found in e.g. `<vector>`, `<list>` and `<iostream>`. This is possible because unlike a class, a namespace can be reopened. `namespace N { int x; } namespace N { int y; }` is valid.

Comment: Ok, but what if I wanted to keep a .h file with all the declarations in one place, could I use a #pragma once? Also what about definition and declaration in a header file and .cpp?

Comment: @marshalcraft: `#pragma once` is a non-portable alternative for a header guard, and not magic that makes your code suddenly have another meaning. As for declarations in headers and definitions in .cpp files, yes, that still fully applies.